# Unknown Characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am reading a text file using Javascript.The file has 81 values, but the length of the array is 97. That means after each line, for some reason javascript reads two extra "empty" characters. When I output them, they show that its an empty string, but when I use `""` or `''` or `null` they are not detected.

The contents of my file are as follows:

```
30025001
14032698
10236500
10245963
10325981
10253002
10326987
78403210
```

If they are not empty characters, then what are they, and how would I filter them.

Comment: How do you read a file using Javascript? Show code, please? Are you sure you're not just seeing CRLF?

Comment: Here Is my code.`var val ;

if(navigator.appName.search('Microsoft')>-1) { val = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP'); }
else { val = new XMLHttpRequest(); } val.open('get', z, true); 
`

Comment: Um, *where?* I can't see any anywhere?

Comment: What you posted only has 64 "characters", 71 if you count simple `\n` linebreaks at the end of all but the last line.

Comment: Removing linebreak/carriage returns: http://jsfiddle.net/wN4Vw/1/

Answer (score 1):

> The file has 81 values,

81 digits, yes.

> but the length of the array is 97

Because you read the whole file, which is not just the digits consecutively. The file also does include 8 linebreaks, each of which seems to consists of [CR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) and [LF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_feed) characters.

Comment: What the OP posted only has 64 "characters" (go figure), but using simple `\n` linebreaks, shows 71: http://jsfiddle.net/wN4Vw/

Comment: @JaredFarrish: oops, you're right. Yet notice that SO normalizes whitespace, so you cannot be sure whether it's `\n` or `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify a Unicode character via the [`String.prototype.charCodeAt(`*`index`*`)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) method.

Once you've isolated the substring you want to identify:

```
substring.charChodeAt( 0 );
```

Comment: Used `if(val.responseText != "\n") if(val.responseText != "\r") arr.push();`But for some reason it doesnt work when I use the "||" in one if statement

Comment: @user2878444 based on your comment it doesn't really look like this answer helped you. [I've written another answer about matching desired characters with RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23185813/356541) but it looks like you may have to provide more code and elaborate on what it is you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure you're seeing the line terminators carriage return and new line (the \r\n sequence).

you can use `alert( str.charCodeAt( 9 ) + ", " + str.charCodeAt( 10 ) )` to verfiy that's the case. it should output `10, 13`, which are the corresponding ascii codes.

the easiest way to remove all non-digits from your string is this:

```
str = str.replace( /[^0-9]/g, "" );
```

Comment: You are right kritxikratzi, but the first character is 48.it outputs 48, 13.So how can I avoid them

Comment: Yeap, you are correct at (9) and (10).It outputs 10, 13.

Comment: ah, sorry... maybe i counted too quickly :) i added a suggestion how to get rid of those characters.

Answer (score 0):

My earlier answer addresses how to determine what character you have on your hands when it appears to be whitespace, but I think you just want to determine whether a character is simply whitespace or not — [RegEx](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) ([the MDN guide is useful for Javascript-specific usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)) is ideally suited to this. Based on your comment in my other answer, you can test whether a character is one of several characters:

```
/[\n\r]/.test( substring )
```

Or you can test whether a character is any piece of whitespace using the RegEx shorthand for whitespace, `\s`:

```
/\s/.test( shorthand )
```

Alternatively, if you know you're only interested in unbroken substrings of numeric characters (digits in string form, aka numbers), you can use the numeric shorthand `\d`:

```
/\d/.test( substring )
```